# Get rows and mark some them that exist on another table

Tags: mysql, join

I have two table. I want to join them together where `users_logs.music_id=users_likes.music_id` and `users_logs.user_id=users_likes.user_id`

This table named users_logs and has repetitive rows.

```
+----+----------+---------+
| id | music_id | user_id |
+----+----------+---------+
| id | 1        | 1       |
+----+----------+---------+
| id | 2        | 1       |
+----+----------+---------+
| id | 1        | 1       |
+----+----------+---------+
| id | 3        | 2       |
+----+----------+---------+
| id | 3        | 1       |
+----+----------+---------+
```

This table named users_likes.

```
+----+----------+---------+
| id | music_id | user_id |
+----+----------+---------+
| id | 1        | 1       |
+----+----------+---------+
| id | 2        | 2       |
+----+----------+---------+
| id | 5        | 1       |
+----+----------+---------+
```

After get descending order last 3 rows from user_logs for `user_id=1` I want below output:

```
1.  music_id = 3   like = 0
2.  music_id = 1   like = 1
3.  music_id = 2   like = 0
```

How can I do this with only 1 query in mysql?

Comment: You have copied the same table for user_likes - please edit it and tell us what your fields are

Comment: Structure of two tables are same but data is different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am following the logic correctly, this query should do what you want.  It assumes that the `id` column specifies the ordering for getting the last three rows from `user_logs`:

```
select ul.music_id, (uli.user_id is not null) as `like`
from (select ul.*
      from user_logs ul
      where user_id = 1
      order by id desc
      limit 3
     ) ul left outer join
     users_likes uli
     on ul.user_id = uli.user_id and ul.music_id = uli.music_id;
```